# Issue on using multiple structures by pointers cause crash on program executing

Tags: c++

Hello I noticed this weird issue when using multiple pointer structures at the same time.
Can somebody explain to me what is causing it ?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct A{
    int x;
}a;

int main()
{
    a *a1, *a2;
    a1->x = 3;
    cout << a1->x << endl; // display "3"
    
    a2->x = 2;
    cout << a2->x << endl; // ...does not display "2" ???

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't add 2 very different language tags unless you want to combine both languages or you are especially interested in the differences.

Comment: You know that a1 and a2 are pointers.  What are they pointing to?

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior, a1 and a2 are not initialized.

Comment: `a1->x = 3;` puts you straight into undefined behavior land where everything is possilbe. `a *a1, *a2;` declares two pointers that are not initialized to point anywhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to do if an uninitialized pointer was used to write memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70401700/what-to-do-if-an-uninitialized-pointer-was-used-to-write-memory)

Comment: what did you actually expect to happen when you wrote `a1->x = 3;` ? What objects member did you intend to access?

Comment: you don't need that typedef stuff  in C++

Comment: You can't assume that C++ code is not fundamentally broken just because it appears to work. Undefined behaviour may sometimes appear to work, and that has tricked you into believing that the use of two (non-existing) structures is relevant to your problem. The actual issue is that there are no structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before assigning the values to your pointers, the pointers have to be initialized properly.

```
a *a1, *a2;
```

These pointers are not initialized. They point to some random location in memory.
The "new" keyword allocates memory for your structure.
You can use it like this:

```
a *a1 = new A, *a2 = new A;
```